# Guard Compile contents of dir to dirname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, guard

I'm using guard to compile coffee-scripts in a Rails 2.3.8 app.

I was previously using bistro_car bundles, so my scripts are organized in app/scripts/{bundle_name}/{bundle_files}

What I would like to do is compile all {bundle_files} to public/javascripts/{bundle_name}.js so I don't have to re-organize everything.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can get using just the `coffee` command is

```
coffee -o public/javascripts/{bundle_name}/ --join \
  --compile app/scripts/{bundle_name}/*.coffee
```

Which will result in a JS file like `app/scripts/{bundle_name}/concatenation.js`.  You could write a pretty simple [Cakefile](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#cake) to iterate over all your bundles.

Comment: I ended up using FSSM and a daemon. Heres the code snippet: http://pastie.org/private/winmsmu6espfuhgofajjcw (lots of refactoring to do yet)